# What is the numeric ID for caps lock?

Tags: c#, dllimport, numeric, keycode, capslock

I need to check if caps lock is pressed, and found a function that requires an int online.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
```

Comment: Um, why don't you write a test program and then see what happens when you press caps lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From googling, I found [this one](http://vcpptips.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/how-to-check-the-caps-lock-is-on-or-off/):

```
void CheckKeyState()
{
   if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001)!=0)
      AfxMessageBox("Caps Lock ON!");
   else
      AfxMessageBox("Caps Lock OFF!");
}
```

With `VK_CAPITAL` being **0x14**.

So you could write in C#:

```
public void CheckKeyState()
{
   if ((GetKeyState(0x14) & 0x0001)!=0)
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock ON!");
   else
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock OFF!");
}
```

Of course, [what Holger says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11545787/107625) makes a lot more sense than using the P/Invoke stuff.

Answer (score 4):

C# also has:

```
if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
```

Keys.CapsLock = 20  (0x14 in hex)